# Horizontal scrolling shortcut in Linux

Tags: linux, scroll-wheel

In Os X, I can hold Shift while using the scroll wheel on the mouse to scroll horizontally instead of vertically. Is there a way to do something similar in Linux?

Comment: I asked a similar question for Windows: http://superuser.com/questions/13763/horizontal-scrolling-shortcut-in-windows

Comment: I'd imagine that would depend on your window manager.

Comment: Doesn't look very difficult to do on a window manager level. I guess you could file a bug in metacity or kdm bugtracker...

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/883789/41425

Answer (score 2):

For a lot of things like this, xmodmap is useful, but I don't think it can remap keyboard+mouse combinations. However, you might have some luck using [imwheel](http://imwheel.sourceforge.net/). It's actually fairly powerful - you can customize to have different mappings in different windows! For example, here's the first section of the sample file included in the source tarball:

```
"^mutt.*"
None,           Up,     Up
None,           Down,   Down
Control_L,      Up,     Page_Up
Control_L,      Down,   Page_Down
```

This will apply to mutt (or rather, windows with titles matching that pattern). The first field is keyboard modifiers for the input event, the second is mouse button/wheel input event, and the third column is output events. So, the first one maps wheel up to keyboard up, and the third maps left control+wheel up to page up.

Answer (score 0):

You could macro the same combination to do the similar action, you would need an alternative to AutoHotKey for your Linux distribution and a script dedicated to Linux.