# How can I scroll efficiently horizontally Microsoft Paint? (Autohotkey maybe)

Tags: windows, macros, autohotkey, microsoft-paint

I just want to use Paint for a whiteboard style sketching on math problems etc. And I really need a way to navigate efficiently on the page.
Maybe even like: hold space + move mouse, to grab the page like in Photoshop.

So is there some config file or hidden shortcut to scroll the page to the left/right? Or maybe there is an easy way in Autohotkey?

Thanks y'all!

Comment: Try the second example on https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1.37

#IfWinActive ahk_class MSPaintApp

+WheelUp::              ; Shift + Wheel Up for horizontal scrolling left
MouseGetPos,,,id, fcontrol,1
; Loop 3 ; <-- Increase for faster scrolling
SendMessage, 0x114, 0, 0, %fcontrol%, ahk_id %id% ; 0x114 is WM_HSCROLL, 0 is SB_LINELEFT
Return

+WheelDown::            ; Shift + Wheel Down for horizontal scrolling right
MouseGetPos,,,id, fcontrol,1
; Loop 3 ; <-- Increase for faster scrolling
SendMessage, 0x114, 1, 0, %fcontrol%, ahk_id %id% ; 0x114 is WM_HSCROLL, 1 is SB_LINERIGHT
Return

#IfWinActive
```

Source: [Horizontal scrolling shortcut in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/13763/horizontal-scrolling-shortcut-in-windows)